# SQL Query for a month calculated daily at set time interval

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying perform a query which returns the following result over a 30 day period. Could someone please advise on how I can perform the following query over say a month?

So the result I would like is a daily range from the datetime field where the time is between 7am and 7am the next day. The query I have below only provides the data for a specific day. I would like it over a fixed period of time between @start and @end if possible.

tagname| date | result

```
Declare @start date, @end date;
set @start = '20160101';
set @end = '20160201';

select tagname, max(value) - min(value) as myRange
from runtime.dbo.AnalogHistory
where tagname = 'SALV_CV005_WX1_TOTAL.PVAI' and datetime between dateadd(hh,7,convert(datetime,@start)) and dateadd(hh,31,convert(datetime,@start))
group by TagName
```

The result I would like should be below

```
date    | tagname | (daily range) 
1/1/16  | XXXX    | 12354
2/1/16  | XXXX    | 2354
3/1/16  | XXXX    | etc
```

Comment: is datetime a field in your AnalogHistory table? If so, include it in both the SELECT and GROUP BY clauses

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want a day to start at 7:00 a.m.  If so, then calculate the date after subtracting 7 hours from the date/time.  If you are not concerned about indexes:

```
Declare @start datetime, @end datetime;
set @start = '20160101';
set @end = '20160201';

select cast(dateadd(hour, -7, datetime) as date) as thedate,
       ah.tagname, max(ah.value) - min(ah.value) as myRange
from runtime.dbo.AnalogHistory ah
where ah.tagname = 'SALV_CV005_WX1_TOTAL.PVAI' and
      cast(dateadd(hour, -7, datetime) as date) between @start and dateadd(day, 1, @end)
group by cast(dateadd(hour, -7, datetime) as date), TagName
order by thedate, tagname;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Declare @start date, @end date;
set @start = '20160101';
set @end = '20163001';

select dateadd(DAY,0, datediff(day,0, datetime))
, tagname
, max(value) - min(value) as myRange
from runtime.dbo.AnalogHistory
where tagname = 'SALV_CV005_WX1_TOTAL.PVAI' 
    and datetime between @start and @end
group by TagName, dateadd(DAY,0, datediff(day,0, datetime))
```

Use the date range for @start and @end. dateadd(DAY,0, datediff(day,0, datetime)) will return the day of the datetime, which you can group by.